# how can find directory

Tags: bash, tcl

when starting the tcl script a directory is created via a bash command. at the end of my script i want to read the directory name of the latest dirs. but my script does not find the newest directory but only the 2nd newest

```
bind pub "-|-" !aa pub:aaa
proc pub:aaa {nick host handle channel arg} {

set home "/home/user"

set bb [exec bash -c "start.sh"]

after 3000
set latest [exec bash -c "ls -td $home/jpg/*/ | head -n1"]
putnow "PRIVMSG $channel :$latest"
}
```

before starting it has the following folders in the directory:

```
drwxr-xr-x 2 user user 4096 Jun 24 18:30  aaa
drwxr-xr-x 2 user user 4096 Jun 24 18:14  bbb
```

after starting it has the following folders in the directory

```
drwxr-xr-x 2 user user 4096 Jun 24 18:30  aaa
drwxr-xr-x 2 user user 4096 Jun 24 18:14  bbb
drwxr-xr-x 2 user user 4096 Jun 24 18:35  ccc
```

output is :

```
 <@testbot> aaa
```

it should be so

```
<@testbot> ccc
```

he finds the directory created during which the tcl script is not running

how can I display the newest, newly created directory?

regards

Comment: try `ls -trd $home/jpg/*/` . Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of trying to exec out to a shell to find the most recently modified directory, I'd do it in pure tcl:

```
proc latest_directory {path {time mtime}} {
    set dirs {}
    foreach dir [glob -nocomplain -type d $path/*] {
        file stat $dir s
        lappend dirs $s($time) $dir
    }
    if {[llength $dirs] == 0} {
        error "No directories found in $path"
    } else {
        return [lindex [lsort -integer -decreasing -stride 2 $dirs] 1]
    }
}


# Then in pub:aaa
set latest [latest_directory $home/jpg]
```

---

As for why you're not getting `ccc`... hard to say for sure without seeing your `start.sh` script, but if it ends up running stuff in the background that continues after it exits, maybe it takes more than 3 seconds to create that directory?